# mssql-server on debian broken after update?

Tags: debian, sqlserver

Time ago I installed mssql-server on my debian VPS and works fine. Now, mssql-server not run and I don't know what is changed.

If type `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlserver` I get

```
2019-07-07 18:13:19.79 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
2019-07-07 18:13:19.79 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
```

If I start service `sudo systemctl start mssql-server` I get

```
jul 07 18:27:23 vps495056 systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
-- Subject: Unit mssql-server.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit mssql-server.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
jul 07 18:27:23 vps495056 sqlservr[28229]: /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr Error: Directory [/var/opt/system/] could not be created.  Errno [13]
jul 07 18:27:23 vps495056 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I created `var/opt/system` directory because it not exist.

```
drwxr-sr-x  2 mssql    mssql     4096 jul  5 18:46 system
```

The mssql config file

```
# cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf 
[EULA]
accepteula = Y

[language]
lcid = 1033
```

I tried reinstalled mssql-server but no luck. I get same errors after that.

Answer (score 0):

A year ago mssql move from root user images into not-root. It made that docker sql-server containers with binded volumes and run on Linux host has a permission issue (=> has no permission to write into binded volume).

There are few solution for this problem:

#### 1. Run docker as root.

eg. compose:

```yml
version: '3.6'
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    user: root
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=BLAH
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/13#issuecomment-641904197

#### 2. Setup proper directory owner (mssql)

1. Check id for mssql user on docker image
   `sudo docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server id mssql`
   gives: `uid=10001(mssql) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`
2. Change folder's owner
   `sudo chown 10001 VOLUME_DIRECTORY`

Source in Spanish: https://www.eiximenis.dev/posts/2020-06-26-sql-server-docker-no-se-ejecuta-en-root/

#### 3. Full access (not recommended)

Give full access to db files on host
`sudo chmod 777 -R VOLUME_DIRECTORY`